# audio/video recording and streaming service/API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backbone.js

I am looking for some third party service or API to integrate with backbone/html 5 application. 
Requirements are as following.
1. There will be on broadcaster and 100-200 viewer. 
2. Broad caster will start video/audio from website and it will be streamed to all viewer. 
3. Video/audio should be realtime should come from camera/mike. 
4. We already looked into option of OpenTok. It is not able to take the load.

Comment: You should take a look at Justin.TV they have the option to make a private stream.

Comment: Justin.tv, it not the solution